# How can chinese display normally in vim?

Tags: vim

I use SecureCRT to ssh linux machine.

secureCRT' appearance is encoded utf-8
[image]

Now I want to open a text including chinese character.

When I input:

```
cat text
```

It can display normally
[image]

But when I open vim, it displays incorrect.
[image]

[image]

What should I do so that my test can display correct in vim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Vim is interpreting the file as `latin1`. Try opening the file explicitly as UTF-8 via

```
:edit ++enc=utf-8 text
```

If that works, check

```
:set fileencodings?
```

Because with the default values (`ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1`), the UTF-8 detection should work out of the box.

If it doesn't work, check

```
:set encoding?
```

If this is not `utf-8`, change the default in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set encoding=utf-8
```

Restart Vim, and try again.